# how to get row index on btn click which is out side of the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a button out of GridView. I want to get the row index on that button click. How to get it?

I used

```
GridViewRow row = ((Button)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
```

but it's not working.

Comment: if the button is outside the `GridView` whats the point of `RowIndex` you should elaborate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Button out of the GridView the Button parent is an other container (maybe a Form or a Panel) not the GridView.

- First of all you need a reference to the GridView. If you have a variable what contains this reference you should use that. If you haven't variable, you should search the GridView:

  ```
  GridView grd = this.FindControl("GridViewName");
  ```
- After that you can get the GridViewRow:

  ```
  GridViewRow row = grd.SelectedRow;
  ```